# set existing KMS to s3 as default encryption using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

when I set SSE-KMS Encryption using cloudformation, they set the KMS key as Custom KMS ARN, but what I want is select existing KMS key with her ID.

here is my template

```
Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'

Properties:

  BucketName: totoKMS

  BucketEncryption:

    ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:

      - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:

          SSEAlgorithm: 'aws:kms'

          KMSMasterKeyID: 03448eab-822f-409f-bf71-511e8f204123

  AccessControl: Private

  VersioningConfiguration:

    Status: Suspended
```

**result :** 
[image]

**expected :**

[image]